SwiftUI List View not updating when (updating before) published property data is retrieved from Firestore
I've seen many similar questions posted, but none yet seemed to provide a solution to my version of the problem.
Simply put, a ForEach List view is not updating (or more accurately I suspect is updating too quickly) when the data in a published property is updated as a result of a get request to Firebase Firestore following the creation of new data in Firestore. I'm tearing my hair out as another near identical list, also connected to Firestore, works as desired - the only differnce I'm aware of being dependency injection of my database service functions.
Details:
Model
struct VenueCollection: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    
    var name: String
    var description: String?
    var venues: [String: Date]  // Where string is venue ID and Date is date added to collection   
}

ViewModel
class AuthViewModel:NSObject, ObservableObject, ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate, ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding {

 @Published var collections: [VenueCollection] = []

 func getUserCollections() {
        guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        
        databaseService.getUserCollections(userID: userID) { [weak self] result in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                switch result {
                case .success(let collections):
                    self?.collections = collections
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error fetching collections: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

Database Service
 func getUserCollections(userID: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[VenueCollection], Error>) -> Void){
        let userPrivateCollectionsRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(userID).collection("private_collections")

        userPrivateCollectionsRef.getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching collections: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(.failure(error))
                return
            }

            let fetchedCollections: [VenueCollection] = snapshot?.documents.compactMap { document in
                try? document.data(as: VenueCollection.self)
            } ?? []
            completion(.success(fetchedCollections))
        }
    }

View
struct CollectionsListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var authViewModel: AuthViewModel
    @Binding var showCreateCollection: Bool
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach (authViewModel.collections) { collection in
                CollectionsRowView(venueCollection: collection)
                    .background(
                        NavigationLink("", destination: CollectionView(venueCollection: collection))
                            .opacity(0)
                    )
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)    
            }
            
            Button {
                showCreateCollection = true
            } label: {
                PrimaryButtonActiveToggle(isActive: true, ButtonText: "Create collection")
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        .onAppear(){
                    authViewModel.getUserCollections()
                }
    }

When a collection is created, a function writes the collection to firebase. I then re-call the getUserCollections function(s) and dismsss the create collection view. Printing out data to the console shows that the count of collections is increased. But the list does not update until navigating away and back to the view, presumably triggering the onAppear getUserCollections, which this time, works.
I can't figure out why, even though there is a delay in getting the data from Firebase, the list doesn't update with the array does.
I've also tried optimistically updating the local array with the new venue, and that didn't update the list either.
Hope I've shared enough/not too much code. Appreciate any help.

Can you please add the sortedCollections declaration to your code?

Good spot. That is a computed variable I was using to filter the list, but I actually get the same results when directly using the published property. I've updated my code to reflect this. I've also added and removed id: .id with no change in behaviour.

I can't figure out the issue either, assuming your EnvironmentObject is set up correctly. Not a great solution but you could hack your way around this by forcing the view to update using .onRecieve or some dummy @State variable

Thanks for taking a look. I'm puzzled by it. Will try your suggestion though.

Fixed the issue - for some reason I was creating a new instance of the view model when presenting the create category view:
sheet(isPresented: $showCreateCollection) {
   NewCollectionView(isPresented: $showCreateCollection)
        .environmentObject(AuthViewModel(databaseService: DatabaseService()))  }

Pretty sure I implemented this to fix some other bug, but it seems to work fine without it and just using the environment object, as it should.
